# How to create Auth Provider using APEX

Tags: apex, oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I could see [AuthProvider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_authprovider.htm) Object support Create() and Update(), But when i try to insert its throwing following error.

> DML operations are not allowing on Auth. Provider

Code:

```
AuthProvider authPro = new  AuthProvider();
authPro.ProviderType = 'OpenIdConnect';
authPro.FriendlyName = 'NewNameFri'
authPro.DeveloperName = 'DeveloperName';
authPro.ConsumerKey = 'consumerKey';
authPro.ConsumerSecret = 'consumerSecret';
authPro.AuthorizeUrl = 'https://auth..com';
authPro.TokenUrl = 'https://auth.xxx.com';
authPro.DefaultScopes = 'manage:xxx-Scope';
authPro.OptionsSendAccessTokenInHeader = true;
authPro.OptionsSendSecretInApis = true;
authPro.OptionsIsPkceEnabled = true;
insert authPro;
```

Even when tried with metadata, the below code throws an error.

```
Metadata.AuthProvider customAuthProvider =  new Metadata.AuthProvider();
system.debug(customAuthProvider);
```

Also, try to link with NamedCredientials. (its for ISV purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform some DML operations in Apex. Instead, use the REST or Metadata API.

Here's some code that works in execute anonymous:

```
class AuthProvider {
    String ProviderType = 'OpenIdConnect';
    String FriendlyName = 'NewNameFri2';
    String DeveloperName = 'DeveloperName2';
    String ConsumerKey = 'consumerKey';
    String ConsumerSecret = 'consumerSecret';
    String AuthorizeUrl = 'https://auth.connect.com';
    String TokenUrl = 'https://auth.xxx.com';
    String DefaultScopes = 'manage:xxx-Scope';
    Boolean OptionsSendAccessTokenInHeader = true;
    Boolean OptionsSendSecretInApis = true;
    Boolean OptionsIsPkceEnabled = true;
}
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v60.0/sobjects/AuthProvider');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(JSON.serialize(new AuthProvider()));
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
```

Comment: throws an error in metadata====Code====
    Metadata.AuthProvider customAuthProvider =  new Metadata.AuthProvider();
    system.debug(customAuthProvider);

Comment: Can you give me the exact name of the metadata way of insert or point me to the right doc ref?

Comment: @Ragul The metadata namespace in Apex is limited to just two types of metadata, not what you're looking for. I've edited in an example of using the REST API.

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I am looking for. :)